# Infer type object of functions in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, flowtype

I try to infer type of function argument (object) using generic and use it in functions inside this argument.

I want infer type of `po` in functions:

```
run({
  methods: {
    calculateNumber: po => (num: number) => po.methods.isActive() ? num : 0,
    isActive: po => () => true,
  },
});

// I want infer follow type corresponding `po`
// type PO = {
//   methods: {
//     calculateNumber: (num: number) => number,
//     isActive: () => boolean,
//   }
// }
```

What I do:

```
// type of po in nested functions
type PO<M> = {
    methods: {
        [K in keyof M]: M[K] extends (...args: any[]) => (...args: infer R) => any ? (...args: R) => any : 'GetMethod never';
    };
};

// incoming type
type Options<M> = {
    methods: {
        [K in keyof M]: M[K] extends (...args: any[]) => (...args: infer R) => any ? (PO: PO<M>) => (...args: R) => any : 'Options never';
        //                                                                                   L___ I suppose here type should infer
    };
};


function run<M>(options: Options<M>) {
    return {} as any;
}
```

When I try to use it, get error, that type `M` equals `unknown`:

```
run({
  methods: {
    calculateNumber: po => (num: number) => po.methods.isActive() ? num : 0,
    //                                                 ^^^^^^^
    //                                                 Property 'onClick' does not exist on type '{}'.               
    isActive: po => () => true,
  },
});
```

`po` infer to type `PO<unknown>`, but I expect `PO<{calculateNumber: ..., isActive: ...}>`.

If I add any primitive type to methods, then type `M` infer with right keys, but with wrong types (as 'Options never'):

```
run({
  methods: {
    foo: 'bar',
    calculateNumber: po => (num: number) => po.methods.isActive() ? num : 0,
 // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 // Type '(po: any) => (num: number) => number' is not assignable to type '"Options never"'              
    isActive: po => () => true,
 // ^^^^^^^^
 // Type '(po: any) => () => boolean' is not assignable to type '"Options never"' 
  },
});
```

If I use primitive type without function, this code works like expected.

My question: Why TS can not infer type of functions (but works with primitive types) or what am I doing wrong?

TypeScript playground: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACg8gHgLID4oF4oG8BQV9QC2EwAFgPYAmAzgFzZ4FMDaA0lAJYB2UA1hCHIAzKEgC69JGzFQIAD2AQuNKAAoAdJoCGAJwDmdKFq4hmYgJQY0G7fsPchEHVABKl9GmMgoAfjWb1XQN6NysjEyh6AHIAcRIkEgpKKC4IADcnKIBuRnwAXxyC3KgcUEgoODBgDnIuamQ0TFwmYjIqQ2amAjZOHn5BEXFJaVkFJRUbQLt6LzN3awCg+y5HZ1CPcO8-VXh6eAb5-1tg10OvSKgoyura6hT0zJymIqKcIQBXLgBjG54dT4aqnIVRqdXo11B9VQlk6+B0JHeOh4WDyRjuXkKxRw-y4qlhRES7Xo+K+WgANl93mStIoAHLvQgAIyc9DA5DCqi4DPoXKZTkObPUrSS1HUHGoAEEfhwMqpLH5eRcAAwAGi66oIxXFUuqGVZ7I2crCwH+EBVxTy5ry5hy2M+eOKwqJDCYQnI5GijN0UXNTFJFKpNIg9L5On1HN5PIZzJ0AvIQsJNDFkulsvlKQZyrVGqYWpTuog4cNhxN7zNFqtNpwOCAA

---

Same working code in flow:

```
/* @flow */

type GetMethod = <R>((...any) => R) => R;

type PO<M> = {|
    methods: {
        ...$Exact<$ObjMap<M, GetMethod>>,
    };
|};

type Methods<P, K> = {|
  [K]: P => (...any) => any,
|}
    
type Options<M> = {|
    methods: M & Methods<PO<M>, $Keys<M>>;
|};

function run<M>(options: Options<M>) {
    return ({}: any);
}
    
run({
  methods: {
    calculateNumber: po => (num: number) => po.methods.isActive() ? num : 0,              
    isActive: po => () => true,
  },
});
```